# Setting a script to run at boot on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-8.04

I need to kick off some processes on server boot, but I need them to run as a specific user.
At the moment I only have a load startup.sh's lying around.

Server is Ubuntu 8.04

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative option, you can put it in the specific user's crontab, like this:

```
@reboot command-to-run
```

Edit: Before I forget, as root, you can edit a specific user's crontab with

```
crontab -u username -e
```

[More documentation](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/372) at Debian Administration.

Comment: You could also place a crontab fragment in /etc/cron.d.  Which I personally prefer over editing a users crontab.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to put a

```
su username -c "/path/to/your/script.sh"
```

in the ubuntu equivalent of *rc.local*.

See [this RcLocalHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto) to prepare your system to have its local init script